# Residuals in TraMineR's seqecmpgroup function

Tags: traminer

In the TraMineR package, the seqecmpgroup function output is a table, for example:

```
Subsequence Support p.value statistic   index   Freq.Low    Freq.Medium Freq.High   Resid.Low   Resid.Medium    Resid.High
1   A-B 0.2685714   0.0000213   21.516234   456 0.1619048   0.2714286   0.3619048   -2.9826924  0.17258979  2.60985584
2   A-C-D   0.2714286   0.0005804   14.903681   495 0.1952381   0.2683673   0.3619048   -2.1192518  -0.1839418  2.51661148
3   C-D-F   0.2614286   0.0013223   13.256739   492 0.1619048   0.2744898   0.3 -2.8207209  0.79968768  1.09319805
```

Are the residuals in the table the standardized residuals?

Answer (score 0):

The residuals provided by `seqecmpgroup` are Pearson residuals returned as `residuals` by the `chisq.test` function. They correspond to `(observed - expected)/sqrt(expected)`, which is the square root of the contribution of each corresponding cell to the Pearson Chi-squared. These are NOT the standardized residuals that `chisq.test` returns as `stdres`.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert! According to Field 2009, the formula you give is the standardized residuals. BTW - what is the index columnr?

Comment: I meant, it is not the standardized residuals that `chisq.test` returns as `stdres`.